# How to turn a dash plotly hosted webpage into a single static html page?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow convert a dash app with a page of graphs and assigned callbacks into a single HTML page to be able to send it around and still got the functionality of the callbacks. So to say convert all python code to javascript which is then embedded into the static HTML page.

I was searching for this already for quite some time, but couldn't find a solution to this, or maybe it's not even possible.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to convert a dash page into a static hmtl file because of how the API runs your code in the browser. This is what gives dash the interactive capabilities.

If you would like to download a plotly graph into a html file then you'll have to create it using vanilla plotly. This html will still retain the interactive features, like zoom, pan, etc, but you won't have the interaction that is utilized in a dash app.